# Prove (in the example) that being homotopic depends on the range of the Homotopy

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Question:

> Define $F : [0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ by $F(x, t) = (\cos(\pi x), (1 - 2t) \sin(\pi x))$. Take a straight-line homotopy between $F(x, 0)$ and $F(x, 1)$. Show that they are homotopic if $X=\mathbb R^2$ and aren't homotopic if $X=\mathbb R^2-{\{O}\}$.

My incomplete answer:

**CASE I:**

Define $f : [0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ by $f(x) = (\cos(\pi x), - \sin(\pi x))$ and $g : [0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ by $g(x) = (\cos(\pi x), \sin(\pi x))$. Both of these maps are examples of paths. They are homotopic, and to show that we take a straight-line homotopy between them. We can call it a straight-line homotopy since for each value of $x\in [0,1]$, we 'deform' $f (x)$ to $g (x)$ along the line segment between them. (parallel lines to y-axis, for illustration) During the homotopy, at each $t$ between $0$ and $1$, we have moved that percentage of the way from $f (x)$ to $g (x)$. The
function $F (x , t)$ is continuous since it is made up of compositions and products of continuous functions. Furthermore, $F(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $F(x, 1) = g(x)$, and therefore $F$ is the desired homotopy. **Am I right?**

**CASE II:**

Let $f$ and $g$ be paths in $\Bbb R^2-{\{O}\}$... (I don't know anymore!).

I don't understand the book's hint for this case: "Show that every path is homotopic to the constant path that sends the entire interval to the path's starting point.", but **what does this statement mean especially 'constant path'?** and **how this leads to the desired result of the original question?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight-line homotopy"? Anyway, that hint does seem fairly useless: every two open paths are homotopy equivalent to a point (which is what the hint is saying), so the meaningful notion of homotopy in this case is that of [path-homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Homotopy_of_paths) (i.e. a homotopy that fixes the two paths' endpoints).

Comment: On the other hand, you should be able to solve this, at least intuitively, once you realise that $F(x,0)$ describes the upper half of the unit circle, while $F(x,1)$ describes the lower half (both including the end-points $(\pm 1,0)$).

Comment: @A.P.: I mean a homotopy of paths are straight lines parallel to y-axis. I can't understand why it makes a big difference when $\mathbb R^2-{\{O}\}$ is the range? Is it because we can't 'draw' the tangent line of a homotopy paths to the 'circle'?

Comment: But in that case you can only say that the two paths are not straight-line homotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{O\}$ (which is trivial, because one of those straight lines would have to pass through $O$), but you cannot say anything about homotopies in general.

Answer (score 0):

For case I, I believe you are correct.

For case II, the *constant path* at a point  **A**is the path associated with the function that maps the entire unit interval to **A**. So intuitively, if a point is travelling along the constant path at a point, it is simply staying there for the entire time duration.

In R^2−{O}, there is no homotopy between f and the constant path at (1,0). I don't want to help out with the exact details, but the intuition is: both the paths are semicircles. There is no way to continuously transform the path (that is essentially what a homotopy between two paths is) without having one of the "intermediate paths" pass through the origin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is $f$? Even in $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{O\}$ both $F(x,0)$ and $F(x,1)$ are homotopy equivalent to the constant path at $(1,0)$, because they are both open paths. On the other hand, they are not *path-homotopy* equivalent to each other. Note that no open path other than a constant path can be path-homotopy equivalent to a constant path, though.